# CODE PEN PROJECT FIRST TIME

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center my image and my order list, but I am having a hard time making it work can someone please give me a tip I tried CSS to align it in the center didn't work. I will place a link so people can see my code and post the code as well.

http://codepen.io/RomingArt/pen/RojXgq

```css
.smaller-image{width:300px
               }
h1 {font-family: Lobster;}
.thick-border{border-color:#14A5A5;
              border-width:3px;
              border-style:solid;
              border-radius:0px;
              text-align:center;}
```

```html
<!-- This is my first tribute page, and I am not sure how to put the picture in the middle also I wanted to put together the list in the middle tried with div did not work hopefully someone will guide me or fix the code so I can learn.-->
<h1 class=" text-primary text-center">Booker T. Washigton</h1>
<h2 class="text-center text-primary"> April 5, 1856-November 14,1915.</h2>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booker_T._Washington" target="blank">
   <img class="smaller-image thick-border"src=http://images.amcnetworks.com/wetv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/bhm_quotes_bwashington.jpg> </a>

<h3> The life of a man who took each opporutnity to learn.</h3>
  <ol>
  <li>1856 – April 5 – Booker T. Washington is born a slave on the Burroughs’ Plantation. </li>
  <li>1861 – Washington’s name appears on Burroughs’ property inventory. His value is $400.00.
</li> 
  <li>1865 – 1871 – Washington works in the salt and coal mines in Malden while attending school, for the first time, in the evenings.</li>
  <li>1872 – Washington leaves his home to attend the Hampton Institute.</li>
  <li>1875 – Washington graduates from the Hampton Institute with honors.</li>
  <li>1875 – 1877 – Washington teaches school, in his hometown of Malden, WV, while helping his brothers (John, and adopted brother James) pay their tuition for the Hampton Institute.</li>
  <li>1881 – July 4 – At age 25, Washington opens the Tuskegee Institute in an old church.</li>
  <li>1887 – Olivia Washington gives birth to Washington’s first son, Booker T. Washington Jr.</li>
  <li>1893 – Washington marries Margaret James Murray who had been Lady Principal of Tuskegee Institute for two years.</li>
  <li>1901 – March – Washington’s most successful autobiography, Up from Slavery, is published.</li>
  <li>1909 – Du Bois helps found the National Association for the Advancement of Colored People (NAACP).</li>
  <li>1915 – November 14 – Washington dies at home in Tuskegee, Alabama.</li>
</ol> 
<p> In order to learn more about the life of Booker T. Washigton click on image to learn about a great man.</p>
```

Comment: Put the image and ol inside a `div` and center the `div` using `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: I gave an up vote, this is a good question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

Add `body{text-align:center;}` as we also have to `text-align:center;` in the parent so that the content will get aligned centrally

```css
body{
  text-align:center;
  }

.smaller-image{width:300px
               }
h1 {font-family: Lobster;}
.thick-border{border-color:#14A5A5;
              border-width:3px;
              border-style:solid;
              border-radius:0px;
              text-align:center;}
```

```html
<!-- This is my first tribute page, and I am not sure how to put the picture in the middle also I wanted to put together the list in the middle tried with div did not work hopefully someone will guide me or fix the code so I can learn.-->
<h1 class=" text-primary text-center">Booker T. Washigton</h1>
<h2 class="text-center text-primary"> April 5, 1856-November 14,1915.</h2>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booker_T._Washington" target="blank">
   <img class="smaller-image thick-border"src=http://images.amcnetworks.com/wetv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/bhm_quotes_bwashington.jpg> </a>

<h3> The life of a man who took each opporutnity to learn.</h3>
  <ol>
  <li>1856 – April 5 – Booker T. Washington is born a slave on the Burroughs’ Plantation. </li>
  <li>1861 – Washington’s name appears on Burroughs’ property inventory. His value is $400.00.
</li> 
  <li>1865 – 1871 – Washington works in the salt and coal mines in Malden while attending school, for the first time, in the evenings.</li>
  <li>1872 – Washington leaves his home to attend the Hampton Institute.</li>
  <li>1875 – Washington graduates from the Hampton Institute with honors.</li>
  <li>1875 – 1877 – Washington teaches school, in his hometown of Malden, WV, while helping his brothers (John, and adopted brother James) pay their tuition for the Hampton Institute.</li>
  <li>1881 – July 4 – At age 25, Washington opens the Tuskegee Institute in an old church.</li>
  <li>1887 – Olivia Washington gives birth to Washington’s first son, Booker T. Washington Jr.</li>
  <li>1893 – Washington marries Margaret James Murray who had been Lady Principal of Tuskegee Institute for two years.</li>
  <li>1901 – March – Washington’s most successful autobiography, Up from Slavery, is published.</li>
  <li>1909 – Du Bois helps found the National Association for the Advancement of Colored People (NAACP).</li>
  <li>1915 – November 14 – Washington dies at home in Tuskegee, Alabama.</li>
</ol> 
<p> In order to learn more about the life of Booker T. Washigton click on image to learn about a great man.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that it is trapped inside the `<a>` tag, and you are only selecting the image to move over, but that would leave the link behind, so the computer says: "that won't work" so it ignores the CSS. What I recommend doing is saying `body {text-align: center;}` and then wrapping a div around the text that you want to be aligned left and saying in the CSS: `div {text-align:left;}`. This will work because CSS is **cascading** and the `div {text-align: left;}` is down from the `body {text-align}` and it will override the first one and the div will be aligned on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Add **text-align:center;** to html and body tag it,s working fine

> html,body{    text-align:center;   }

```css
.smaller-image{width:300px
               }
h1 {font-family: Lobster;}
.thick-border{border-color:#14A5A5;
              border-width:3px;
              border-style:solid;
              border-radius:0px;
              text-align:center;
}
html,body{
   text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<!-- This is my first tribute page, and I am not sure how to put the picture in the middle also I wanted to put together the list in the middle tried with div did not work hopefully someone will guide me or fix the code so I can learn.-->
<h1 class=" text-primary text-center">Booker T. Washigton</h1>
<h2 class="text-center text-primary"> April 5, 1856-November 14,1915.</h2>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booker_T._Washington" target="blank">
   <img class="smaller-image thick-border"src=http://images.amcnetworks.com/wetv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/bhm_quotes_bwashington.jpg> </a>

<h3> The life of a man who took each opporutnity to learn.</h3>
  <ol>
  <li>1856 – April 5 – Booker T. Washington is born a slave on the Burroughs’ Plantation. </li>
  <li>1861 – Washington’s name appears on Burroughs’ property inventory. His value is $400.00.
</li> 
  <li>1865 – 1871 – Washington works in the salt and coal mines in Malden while attending school, for the first time, in the evenings.</li>
  <li>1872 – Washington leaves his home to attend the Hampton Institute.</li>
  <li>1875 – Washington graduates from the Hampton Institute with honors.</li>
  <li>1875 – 1877 – Washington teaches school, in his hometown of Malden, WV, while helping his brothers (John, and adopted brother James) pay their tuition for the Hampton Institute.</li>
  <li>1881 – July 4 – At age 25, Washington opens the Tuskegee Institute in an old church.</li>
  <li>1887 – Olivia Washington gives birth to Washington’s first son, Booker T. Washington Jr.</li>
  <li>1893 – Washington marries Margaret James Murray who had been Lady Principal of Tuskegee Institute for two years.</li>
  <li>1901 – March – Washington’s most successful autobiography, Up from Slavery, is published.</li>
  <li>1909 – Du Bois helps found the National Association for the Advancement of Colored People (NAACP).</li>
  <li>1915 – November 14 – Washington dies at home in Tuskegee, Alabama.</li>
</ol> 
<p> In order to learn more about the life of Booker T. Washigton click on image to learn about a great man.</p>
```

Comment: yes except this aligns all of it and he just wants the image to be aligned.

Comment: @T.Bragg read his question well,first sentence "I am trying to center my image and **my order list**"

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to center your image and list items only. Is it right?
If not, just add `text-align: center` to `h1,h2` tags in your css and your title will be centered also.

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.inside {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.smaller-image{width:300px
               }
h1 {font-family: Lobster;}
.thick-border{border-color:#14A5A5;
              border-width:3px;
              border-style:solid;
              border-radius:0px;
              text-align:center;}
```

```html
<!-- This is my first tribute page, and I am not sure how to put the picture in the middle also I wanted to put together the list in the middle tried with div did not work hopefully someone will guide me or fix the code so I can learn.-->

<h1 class=" text-primary text-center">Booker T. Washigton</h1>
<h2 class="text-center text-primary"> April 5, 1856-November 14,1915.</h2>
<div class="wrapper">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booker_T._Washington" target="blank">
   <img class="smaller-image thick-border"src=http://images.amcnetworks.com/wetv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/bhm_quotes_bwashington.jpg> </a></div>
<div class="content">
<div class="inside">
<h3> The life of a man who took each opporutnity to learn.</h3>
  <ol>
  <li>1856 – April 5 – Booker T. Washington is born a slave on the Burroughs’ Plantation. </li>
  <li>1861 – Washington’s name appears on Burroughs’ property inventory. His value is $400.00.
</li> 
  <li>1865 – 1871 – Washington works in the salt and coal mines in Malden while attending school, for the first time, in the evenings.</li>
  <li>1872 – Washington leaves his home to attend the Hampton Institute.</li>
  <li>1875 – Washington graduates from the Hampton Institute with honors.</li>
  <li>1875 – 1877 – Washington teaches school, in his hometown of Malden, WV, while helping his brothers (John, and adopted brother James) pay their tuition for the Hampton Institute.</li>
  <li>1881 – July 4 – At age 25, Washington opens the Tuskegee Institute in an old church.</li>
  <li>1887 – Olivia Washington gives birth to Washington’s first son, Booker T. Washington Jr.</li>
  <li>1893 – Washington marries Margaret James Murray who had been Lady Principal of Tuskegee Institute for two years.</li>
  <li>1901 – March – Washington’s most successful autobiography, Up from Slavery, is published.</li>
  <li>1909 – Du Bois helps found the National Association for the Advancement of Colored People (NAACP).</li>
  <li>1915 – November 14 – Washington dies at home in Tuskegee, Alabama.</li>
</ol> 
<p> In order to learn more about the life of Booker T. Washigton click on image to learn about a great man.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```